# Cannot find protocol declaration 'FIRMessagingDelegate'

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to add Firebase Messaging to my iOS app. I've followed the steps in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-audience), namely:

- Uploaded the APNs Certificate
- Imported Firebase and added `[FIRApp configure]`
- Imported Firebase Messaging with `@import FirebaseMessaging` and added `FIRMessagingDelegate`

However at this point I get an error:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>      
// Cannot find protocol declaration for FIRMessagingDelegate
```

I've updated my pods (suggested by similar issues found on Stack Overflow), but still get the same error. To confirm, running `pod update` gives the following output:

```
 Using FirebaseMessaging (1.2.2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the source of your problem and where you able to solve it?

Comment: @coder I was able to solve the same problem by using MessagingDelegate instead. Apparently it was renamed.

Answer (score 11):

The issue seems to be that the `FIRMessagingDelegate` protocol is declared in the new `FirebaseMessaging` framework.

Simply add:

```
@import FirebaseMessaging;
```

See more at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Protocols/FIRMessagingDelegate

and the sample app `AppDelegate.m` here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m#L62-L85

Comment: I already have that import statement in my AppDelegate.m. I am importing Firebase, FirebaseMessaging, and UserNotifications.

Comment: Great, however it still can't find the declaration... I'd look into the `podfile` and the cocoapod gem. It might need to be updated with `[sudo] gem install cocoapods`. Then you should do a `pod update` and it should be fine.

Comment: in my case i forgot to add @import UserNotifications;

Answer (score 2):

I found this useful in the pod file:

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
to
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Now all dependencies are found.

Answer (score 0):

Because my search brought me here, going to share this here:

If you're on Swift and getting this error, the 'FIR' prefix was dropped across all names, so you'll just use 'MessagingDelegate' instead of 'FIRMessagingDelegate'

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide